# Cannot write to directory using Faker image

Tags: laravel, faker

I want to setup a test data through Faker using a factory. but when I try to add images to the model

```
        "images" => $faker->image('public/storage/images',400,300, null, false),
```

it returns an error

> Cannot write to directory "public/storage/images"

even thought I ran

```
php artisan storage:link
```

How to solve this problem? I am using Ubuntu btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are attempting to write to the directory `public/storage/images`, this is relative to the root of your server as in `/public/storage/images`.

You have to write to the storage directory of your app, such as:

```
$faker->image(storage_path('images'),400,300, null, false)
```

Or directly to the public folder as well:

```
$faker->image(public_path('images'),400,300, null, false)
```

Comment: In Laravel 8 I get the same error, but then how about when executing `Storage::makeDirectory('images');` How do I change to `public_path()`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the user-group or system cannot write to the folder. `php artisan storage:link` only creates a symlink to the public folder.

You need to update the permissions on the storage folder to allow creation of files. Check that the user group running the code has permission to write to the storage file and that the storage file has the proper CHMOD permissions

`chmod -R 755 storage`

Comment: It'd better be `755`.  `777` shouldn't be advised. [More about it here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/faker-images-cannot-write-to-directory).